# HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure with app.UseStaticFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-6.0

When I;m adding this in Progarm file

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images")),
    RequestPath = "/Images"
});
```

This Error comes HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure
but i need the above code in Program file

I have tried what google suggested but not working

Comment: HTTP error 502 is bad gateway.  You are completing the HTTP connection otherwise you would not be getting a response.  So my best guess would be the Route "/Images" is not being found in server.

Comment: I don't find any error in your code,i test in local and it works fine, Do you get this error after you host your project on IIs or another server?

Comment: I get it after hosting. But find the Solution Thank You

Comment: Now i want to display the StaticFiles images in front. but can't do it. Can you help me in this?